# How to gain S-OFF on HTC Salsa

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, rooting

I want to root my **HTC Salsa** phone. [According to this link](http://theunlockr.com/2012/10/23/how-to-root-the-htc-salsa/) I need to gain **S-OFF** on my Mobile.

There is nice [article to gain S-OFF](http://web.archive.org/web/20120101221426/http://rebel-xtc-clip.com/support-how-to-use-rebel-xtc-clip.html).

But my Question: Is there an alternative way, **without using any hardware** to gain **S-OFF** ?

Comment: I've just added your device to our [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/1185/16575) (linking here), as it is not yet covered on our site. You might want to check the questions on other HTC devices linked from there, as S-OFF is a HTC speciality. It might turn up something useful, until a direct answer turns up here. If you found a solution yourself, feel free to answer your own question and accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

the Salsa is supported by the official **[HTCdev bootloader unlock process](http://www.htcdev.com/)**

While this does not make your phone S-OFF (which would allow overwriting things like the radio software), it does make enough of the partitions writable to install custom recoveries like ClockWorkMod, root the device (by installing rooting packages like superuser or SuperSU), and install custom ROMs that don't need updated bootloaders (the vast majority).

Comment: Not Helpful buddy, Because that will not increase my Internal Memory.

Comment: 1) Nothing will increase the physical amount of memory. 2) Most methods to deal with lack of memory in a certain partition only require root or custom ROMs (app2SD, etc.) so work fine with HTC unlock. 3) Are you talking about some sort of bizarre repartitioning process?